# How can I change the value of an Angular template variable?

Tags: angular

I want to change the value of a template variable based on a condition.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="'first' as myVar">
  <ng-container *ngIf="myVar == 'first'">
    <ng-container *ngIf="'later' as myVar">
      <div>{{myVar}}</div>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <div>{{myVar}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

However I am getting

```
later
first
```

instead of

```
later
later
```

(probably the second variable is different than the first one and exists only in the scope of the second variable (which seems to be a weird way to implement template variables)).

**Is there a simple way to change the value of a template variable?**

**I would also like to know** if there is a way to join the condition (`"myVar == 'first'"`) and the assignment (`"'later' as myVar"`) into one expression instead of two nested `<ng-container>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Template Variables

For your main question, your elements can only see the the template variables of their parents.

For example, **this** will fail to compile:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="'later' as myVar">
  <div>{{myVar}}</div>
</ng-container>
<div>{{myVar}}</div> <!-- No parent TV or reference in component.ts -->
```

So your conclusion is right, in that it is a different value, although it isn't all that weird if you think of it as living on that DOM-Element. They are more so meant as references to that particular element, and are indeed less useful for logic. For that you're better off binding to your *component.ts* file.

*In short, I don't think reassigning of Template Variables is possible. You will just get the value of the closest parent.*

### Second Question

For your second question, this is a little shorter (but /w same result):

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="'first' as myVar">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(myVar == 'first' ? 'later' : '') as myVar">
    <div>{{myVar}}</div>
  </ng-container>
  <div>{{myVar}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

You could also (ab)use `ngTemplateOutlet` to achieve something similar:

```html
<ng-template #s [ngTemplateOutlet]="s" let-a [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: 'first' }">
    {{a}}
    <ng-template #t [ngTemplateOutlet]="t" let-b [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: a == 'first' ? 'later' : '' }">
    {{b}}
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csg31j?file=src/app/app.component.html) for you.

### Presentation Logic in Component.ts

It is actually perfectly fine to have logic for presentation in your component. In fact it is pretty much the only thing that should be in your **presentation components**.

It is a best practice to use the approach of **Container & Presentation Components**.

##### Container component

- Manages the state by interacting with service/store
- Contains only minor presentation, like for example a header/title
- Passes state to presentation components using input properties

##### Presentation component

- Presents/renders the data, but does not directly interact with state
- Communicates with container component using output properties

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to actually refer to my question :) It's Angular, do I don't know if I should or shouldn't be surprised that such a standard mechanism is not implement in a straightforward way unlike so many other front-end frameworks... I've read before about the pattern you are suggesting. I have some disagreement with this strategy which is why I don't use it. But even if I did, some things about exporting data to HTML you really want to do in the template. Otherwise 1. You go through the data twice, both in the component and in the template (bad performance, kills battery).

Comment: 2. You end up with a lot of boilerplate classes just to hold the manipulated data that you will hand on to the dumb template, even if the manipulation is quite trivial (with a common-sense framework, i.e. not Angular). 3. You cannot naturally use one component with multiple alternative templates... you will tend to recreate multiple (quite similar) components for every small variation of template.

Comment: I've gone through many SO answers trying to find a simple built-in way to change variable values and could not find any. Your answer is detailed and seems to be correct in describing the basic ways to change variable values within templates. So I will accept it as the solution. However because I think it's a useful mechanism to have in order to write more readable and maintainable code, I have developed my own way to do it. P.S. If someone thinks they have found a better way to do it, they are welcome to post it here.

Comment: @rapt I'm curious to your implementation. Btw, if there is an event thrown by the dom at the time you want to do the assigning it is possible to do so. You can provide a function to a binding event. I created an example using a hidden tag to store a value in the same Stackblitz. I don't think it's exactly what you were looking for, but this problem has kept me thinking today. XD

Comment: My idea is quite simple. Use a service/component method to change the value of a service/component variable from a template. This way you bypass the template variable scope problem. So you will have get and set methods. It's readable and intuitive.

Comment: I don't use some of the Angular syntax because it's so unreadable, over complicated and often just forces/encourages you to do things the wrong way. Sometimes they just invent a non-existent problem just to solve it by another load of cryptic syntax (think: Captain Jean-Luc Picard face palm). I guess user-friendliness and KISS were not at the top of their TODO list.

Answer (score 0):

Angular allows you to set a ternary expression inside the structural directives such as `*ngIf="argument === value ? true : false "`
[Here is a stackblitz to show you this in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehbfny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). (Change the value of name from Angular to React in the link to see how `*ngIf=""` will behave)

Thus you do not need to nest `*ngIf=""` the way is done in your code above.You can also do the ternary expressions in the 'controller' - Typescript file and that's cleaner and more readable.

Such as:

```
public isAngular: boolean = this.name === 'Angular' ? true : false
```

And then you bind `isAngular` to your template `*ngIf=""`.

You can also use `*ngIf="condition; else fallback"` where `fallback` is a template reference to another content `<ng-template #fallback>content goes here</ng-template>`

Comment: Sorry, not clear... 1. You have not answered my first (and main) question... 2. It's not clear how you use the ternary expression to combine together the condition and assignment... 3. What was `name` and where was it initialized?

Comment: I knew about the `*ngIf="condition; then reference_1; else reference_2"` syntax. But as far as I can see it just splits the template (with some cumbersome structure). It does not let me change the value of template variable (or at least I fail to see how it does). So it's still not clear why you think this is relevant to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="myVar === 'first'" else #later>
   <div>{{myVar}}</div>
   <div>{{myVar}}</div>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-template #later *ngIf="myVar === 'later'" >
   <div>{{myVar}}</div>
   <div>{{myVar}}</div>
 </ng-template>
```